# Подсветка текста

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, я хочу сделать такую программу, которая распознает, если в richTextBox'e есть слово "делал", то выделить его зеленым, если есть слово "нарубил", то выделить его красным. Ну, короче, как в IDE.

Comment: Это не в компиляторах, это в редакторах кода:)

Comment: @Angus123, А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Как делать такие выделения цветом?

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, самому предстоит это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        private readonly List<string> _reservedWords = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            _reservedWords.Add("begin");
            _reservedWords.Add("end");
            ....
        }
        private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar != ' ') return;
            var searchWord = "";
            var startIndex = 0;
            for (var i = richTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var ch = richTextBox1.Text[i];
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == Convert.ToChar("\n") || ch == Convert.ToChar("\r")) break;
                searchWord = ch + searchWord;
                startIndex = i;
            }
            if(_reservedWords.IndexOf(searchWord)== -1) return;
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = startIndex;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = searchWord.Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, richTextBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart += richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, richTextBox1.Font.Size);
        }
```

при нажатии на "пробел" выделяется жирным синем цветом слово если оно есть в списке.

Answer (score 2):

Идея простая: искать ключевые слова, задавать нужный цвет выделения и выделять их.

```
// Создать строку для поиска слова "текст".
String searchString = "текст";
// Определить местонахождение слова "текст".
int index = rtb.Text.IndexOf(searchString);
// Определить, если слово найдено, и выбрать его.
if (index != -1)
{
    // Выбрать цвет подсветки
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    // Выбрать строку, используя индекс и длину строки.
    rtb.Select(index, searchString.Length);
}
```

Comment: Не тут какая-то ошибка,он выделяет все, после чего цвет почему-то не меняется, и если стереть "текст", то ты продолжаешь писать красным....